# OCR Captcha through VBA

Tags: vba, ocr, captcha

I have been trying access a web site and OCR a captcha.
But this captcha part I have no idea how to proceed.

Can someone walk me through this?

```
1. Access website
2. Donwload captcha image (?)
3. OCR it
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to learn about HTTP and image recognition.  You also need to use a better language than VBA.

Comment: I assume your intentions are good, right?

Comment: Yes, they certainly are. I am doing an automation project for the company I work for.

Comment: Hi SLaks, I have to use VBA, there are no options left here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading a file from the web can be done with the `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` object:

```
Dim myURL As String
myURL = "http://www.somesite.com/captcha.png"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile ("C:\captcha.png")
    oStream.Close
End If
```

Snippet Copied from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd0ee306-7bb5-4ce4-8341-edd9475f84ad/excel-2007-use-vba-to-download-save-csv-from-url?forum=isvvba)

However, In order to run OCR on the image you just downloaded, you'll need to use an ActiveX component,

After googling, I came up with [this component](http://www.dtksoft.com/dtkocr.php), and I haven't found anything free.

Comment: Tell me something.. is it possible to download a picture from a website using Selenium Wrapper?

Comment: maybe, I am not familiar with Selenium Wrapper